# Vue 3 TypeScript optional props object checking length - error

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I need props to be an object that is optional.

```
interface MyObject { id: string| number, name: string, namePlural: string}
interface Props { preloadInputs?: MyObject}
```

...
// check if preloadInputs is not empty:

```
onMounted(() => {if (!(Object.keys(props.preloadInputs).length === 0)) {...} })
```

VSCode's error for the *props.preloadInputs* is:

I get an error:

> No overload matches this call
> Overload 1 of 2, ' (o: {}): string[]', gave the following error.
> Overload 2 of 2, ' (o: object): string[]', gave the following error.ts (2769)

I am new to Vue and TS, so there must be something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `preloadInputs` to be optional so it can have a value of `undefined`. `Object.keys()` does not accept `undefined` as the argument. That's why you get the error `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{}'`.

We could use the [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) operator to solve this problem.

```
Object.keys(props.preloadInputs ?? {}).length === 0
```

If `props.preloadInputs` is `undefined`, an empty object gets passed to `Object.keys()`.